# How to Centralize a Float on the Screen (such horizontally as vertically) Using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

good afternoon,

I'd like to create an area placed in the center of the screen using floats with fixed values for both width and height. this area must be centralized even when the screen is resized. my objective is to centralize on the screen the field Password, the buttom Login and an image. these elements must be placed within a float which must be centralized on the screen.

I'd appreciate your help.

thanks,

Comment: "these elements must be placed within a float which must be centralized on the screen." I think you don't know what `float` means for CSS. Please provide the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: hi Nico, I've created and centralized the float horizontally but I also want to centralize it vertically. I've put all those elements in the float and it worked but unfortunately not vertically centralized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this to the div,

```
   .center {
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       top: 50%; 
       margin-left: -150px;
       margin-top: -150px;
    }
```

Negative margins are exactly half the height and width, which pull the element back into perfect center. Only works with elements of a fixed height/width.

**Updated:**

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LX4uR/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I just whipped up:

The `position:absolute;` div will ALWAYS be center, no matter what browser height/width.

The form I just threw in to prove that it works.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2z9v/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <form>
      <input style='width:45%;float:left;' placeholder='Username'/>
      <input style='width:45%;float:right;' placeholder='Password'/>
      <input style='width:45%;float:left;' placeholder='email'/>
      <input style='width:45%;float:right;' placeholder='favourite color'/>
      <p style='clear:both;'></p>
      <input type='submit' value='Go'/>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
div{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: hi JsFiddle, this code above worked as mine did. it centralizes horizontally. but, when I resize the window, it doesn't resize top and bottom margins as it does with the left and right margins.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are expecting [Here for jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/R5g6z/1/)

all i did is to balance height/width with margin and since it is % and not in px it will always stay in center

```
<div class="center"><input type="text"><input type="password"></div>
```

and css

```
    .center {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444444;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    }
    .center input {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```